# How to Deserialize JSON.NET text using C# from Autodesk PLM

Tags: c#, json.net

I read a number of answers and tried several times but I could not get this work.

- I have a JSON text which is the result I retrieve from our company's PLM system.
- I use json2csharp com to convert JSON text to class(es)
- To make the problem simple, I only want to get the `descriptor` which is `"ID000001 - BMW - 2342152"` and the `AFFECTED_PLANTS_SYSTEM1` which `value = "HT"`

I tried several possible Class Name for on

```
        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(jText);
        var token = (JArray)jObj.SelectToken("List");


        foreach (var item in token)
        {
           string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.SelectToken("item"));

        }
```

But `"List"`, `"Item"`, `"Details"`....all return `token is null object`

I tried dynamic, etc... but I cannot get anything and I am think about just extract text using string manipulation. Any help will be appreciated.

```
{
  "list": {
    "item": [
      {
        "uri": "https://MyFirm.autodeskplm360.net/api/rest/v1/workspaces/921/items/258",
        "id": 258,
        "description": "ID000001 - BMW - 2342152",
        "details": {
          "descriptor": "ID000001 - BMW - 2342152",
          "workspaceID": 921,
          "deleted": false,
          "versionID": 145,
          "version": 1,
          "timeStamp": "2018-01-29T15:22:44.399-05:00",
          "lastModified": "2018-02-22T08:11:44.263-05:00",
          "createdByUser": {
            "uri": "https://MyFirm.autodeskplm360.net/api/rest/v1/users/IvSYN",
            "id": "IvSYN",
            "userNumber": 0
          },
          "owner": {
            "uri": "https://MyFirm.autodeskplm360.net/api/rest/v1/users/IvSYN",
            "id": "IvSYN",
            "userNumber": 0
          },
          "additionalOwners": {
            "group": null,
            "user": null
          },
          "lifecycleState": {
            "stateID": 0,
            "stateName": "Work In Progress",
            "effectivity": false
          },
          "lifecycleStatus": "Working",
          "latest": true,
          "working": true,
          "workflowState": {
            "stateId": 457,
            "stateName": "Form Distributed"
          },
          "lastModifiedBy": {
            "uri": "https://MyFirm.autodeskplm360.net/api/rest/v1/users/IvSYN",
            "id": "IvSYN",
            "userNumber": 0
          },
          "status": "Unreleased",
          "dmsID": 258
        },
        "metaFields": {
          "entry": [
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_PART_NUMBERS",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "234\2453\4646\2324",
                "formattedValue": "234\2453\4646\2324",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_PLANTS_SYSTEM2",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "MO",
                "formattedValue": "MO",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "SUPPLIER_PCN_NUMBER",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "2342152",
                "formattedValue": "2342152",
                "dataType": "Single Line Text"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_CUSTOMERS_SYSTEM0",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "na",
                "formattedValue": "na",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "SUPPLIER",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "BMW",
                "formattedValue": "BMW",
                "dataType": "Single Line Text"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_PLANTS_SYSTEM0",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "No access",
                "formattedValue": "No access",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "SYSTEM FAILTURE",
                "formattedValue": "SYSTEM FAILTURE",
                "dataType": "Single Line Text"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "IMPACT",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "3",
                "label": "PPAP",
                "dataType": "Radio Button"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_PLANTS_SYSTEM1",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "HT",
                "formattedValue": "HT",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "DATE_OF_PCN",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "2018-10-09 00:00:00.0",
                "formattedValue": "10/09/2018",
                "dataType": "Date"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "NOTE",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "None",
                "formattedValue": "None",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_CUSTOMERS_SYSTEM2",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "BWM (MA)",
                "formattedValue": "BWM (MA)",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_CUSTOMERS_SYSTEM1",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "na",
                "formattedValue": "na",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "ID",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "ID000001",
                "formattedValue": "ID000001",
                "dataType": "Auto Number"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_CUSTOMERS_SYSTEM3",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "AT",
                "formattedValue": "AT",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            }
            ,
            {
              "key": "AFFECTED_CUSTOMERS_SYSTEM3",
              "fieldData": {
                "value": "HONDA",
                "formattedValue": "HONDA",
                "dataType": "Paragraph"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "relations": {
          "entry": [
            {
              "key": "REV0",
              "value": null
            },
            {
              "key": "REV1",
              "value": null
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to parse that json text with Newtonsoft.JSon, using `dynamic`:

```
dynamic jobject = JObject.Parse(jText);
string descriptor = jobject.list.item[0].details.descriptor;
JArray metaFields = jobject.list.item[0].metaFields.entry;
var array = metaFields.ToObject<dynamic[]>();
var part = array
       .Where(d => d.key == "AFFECTED_PART_NUMBERS")
       .Select(d => d.fieldData.value).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is case-sensitive. You should use `list` instead of `List`. And this is invalid to cast `list` to `JArray`, since it's an object. Instead, use the following code, if you want to get the JSON string of each item:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(jText);
var token = (JArray)jObj.SelectToken("list").SelectToken("item");

foreach (var item in token)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
    // Process 'json' here...
}
```